# "Take this test to find out if you are..." type of module in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I'd like to have a test like the ones that show up in magazines, where users answers a bunch of questions about themselves and at the end the get a score that says something about them.

Example:

*"Take this test to see what type of learner are you"
Question #1
Question #2
...
Question #n
"You ranked XXX, so you are a Visual Learner!"*

Is there a module for that or should I implement one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiz + custom module only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it able to calculate a ranking and result, but have a look at the [Quiz](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) module.